# Exporting SQLite database from another android application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have applications number 1 and 2. Is that possible, that application nr.2 can export SQLite Database of application number 1 to local phone storage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible and I believe you should use a content provider or content providers. [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)